# best way of dimensionality reduction with respect to model(classifier) performance

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, pca, feature-selection

in my theoretical studies I faced the term *Curse of Dimensionality* so many times that when I started implementing those ideas in real world(in particular music genre classification) after getting about 5000 thousand features for only 1000 individual songs, first thing I did as a no-brainer was to perform PCA on it. However my model performed worst than the baseline(the classifier on the raw data). I then made some research and found out about *blessing of non-uniformity* and then a colleague told me about the superiority of wrapper methods(like sequential forward selection) to filter methods(like PCA). I then made some further research and found out about random forest dimensionality reduction and now my main question is: which method performs better with respect to classifier accuracy?

**edit 1**: I have 5 classes in this problem and I have 1000 features per class and only about 1000 data points

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! After you've seen your PCA approach result in inferior performance, why do you want to reduce the dimension at all?

Comment: @Dave really nice question, I forgot to mention this but I have 5 classes(I would update the question) and for each class in the data I have 1000 features so if model find only one feature that gives the perfect discrimination for one class it would get a training error of 0 but it would clearly be overfitted